# PC won't recognize unlocked SGH-A847 cell phone

Tags: windows-7, usb

My wife bought a used Samsung Rugby II (SGH-A847) to replace her old one of the same model (because she loves her old flip-phone and doesn't want a smart phone).  To access data on the phone from a PC, we have to use Samsung's proprietary New PC Studio (NPS), but NPS will not recognize the new phone.

After several hours of troubleshooting, I discovered that the issue has to do with the phone being unlocked.  (We didn't unlock it; it came that way.)  Part of the process of unlocking the phone involved switching its USB configuration to Qualcomm Mode, which caused the phone to show up in Windows' Device Manager as

- Other Devices

  - Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
  - Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
  - Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM

for which Windows refuses to automatically find drivers for.

After manually finding and installing questionable drivers of dubious origin for these devices, the phone now shows up in the Device Manager as

- Modems

  - Qualcomm HS-USB Modem 9002
- Ports (COM & LPT)

  - Qualcomm HS-USB Diagnostics 9002
  - Qualcomm HS-USB NMEA 9002

However, NPS still won't acknowledge the phone when it's connected.  The three new "modem" and "port" devices show up under NPS's "search for bluetooth or serial connection," but trying all three of them results in "no device is connected."

Our next option is to buy a bluetooth USB dongle and see if that works, but instead of having to spend more money, we're hoping somebody can answer this question:

**How do I switch the phone's USB configuration back to regular USB mode?**  Or is there something else I can do to make NPS recognize the phone?

I assume there must be a simple code to do this since punching in a code (*#782872#) is all it takes to instantly configure Qualcomm mode.  I found instructions on how to get into the administrator menu, but I didn't seen anything there that looked useful.

Extra info:  I stuck a micro SD card in the new phone and confirmed that Mass Storage mode works, but that mode still can't access the data which actually resides on the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I switch the phone's USB configuration back to regular USB
>   mode?

Try entering *#726872# to switch back to regular USB mode.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/519139)

Comment: How does it not provide an answer to the question? Maybe I misinterpreted the information he was seeking. 
Wasn't this his question:
"How do I switch the phone's USB configuration back to regular USB mode? Or is there something else I can do to make NPS recognize the phone?"

Please enlighten me so I can try to provide the best answer to him.

Comment: @Ramhound As far as you implying he will be requiring clarification, I'm not sure how much more specific I could go other than describing to him the best way to use his fingers and hands to pick up the phone and push the keys. I can make a video showing these steps if he requests.

Comment: @Nic, Welcome to SU. You could improve the answer by making it less tentative ("try ..." and "Hope ...") and by adding some link or reference to where that star-hash code is documented for that phone make/model. For long complicated questions, where the actual question doesn't exactly match the title, I usually highlight the specific part I am answering at the beginning of my answer, like this: `> **How do I switch the phone's USB configuration back to regular USB mode?**` - Just my $0.02 worth.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @RedGrittyBrick, I will keep it in mind if I post an answer in the future. I personally prefer direct uncomplicated answers when they are in response to such a well written & detailed question. His question was not complicated, he explained everything well enough for a simple answer to be sufficient.

Comment: 1. I'll remove my line of hopeful encouragement in case it makes him or anyone second guess the answer. I still think my answer is worth a _try_ though.

2. I have no link or reference for where this code is officially documented, because I don't think it is. Hence the reason he is here asking for it. 

3. His question is not long and complicated, it's short and simple. It's also not that different than the title, the answer I provided should fix the problem however it's asked.

  I'll edit to include his quoted question. (Even though he did this himself, which is the reason I didn't bother)

Comment: @Nic, thank you for your succinct answer.  I tried that and it worked!  (I'll refrain from asking for clarification since clearly none is needed.)